# Why this "is not a correctly specified region"?

Tags: regions

I want to subtract one `Cuboid[]` form another `Cuboid[]`. This is the code I use:

```
RegionPlot3D@ RegionDifference[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}],Cuboid[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5}]]
```

but I get the error:

> RegionDifference::reg: "Cuboid[{1,1,1},{-1,-1,-1}] is not a correctly
>   specified region. "

On the other hand, the code:

```
RegionPlot3D@ RegionDifference[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}],Cuboid[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]]
```

works:

[image]

`Graphics3D` and `Show` can  visualize the two cube:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2],Cuboid[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5}]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}]}]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Graphics3D can be forgiving but in general the first point should be a lower one. Not sure where exactly does it matter but I recall a question where lighting of cuboid was broken on MacOS due to that reversed spec, worked on Windows.

Comment: @Kuba that is a bug then, or do you see a rationale that will justify such restriction?

Comment: @rhermans it is the first line in Cuboid docs :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of Cuboid states:

[image]

So just reorder your arguments:

```
d = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   Cuboid[{-0.5, -0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]];
HighlightMesh[d, Style[2, Opacity[0.3]]]
```

[image]